# To which noun does "bent on escaping these sufferings" refer?

Tags: grammar

Here is an extract from a book about the Buddha by Michael Carrithers:
[image]

I wonder to which noun the clause **bent on escaping these sufferings** refers. I think it refers to *the Buddha* considering the comma before the clause; referring to the *wandering ascetic* it would not need the comma before it.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the participial phrase were intended to modify the subject, I would expect the two to be closer:

- Bent on escaping these sufferings, he also saw a wandering ascetic.
- He, bent on escaping these sufferings, also saw a wandering ascetic.

I don't know the author's intent, but I can offer a couple of probable explanations for the comma in question:

Carrithers may view the participial phrase as a parenthetical construction.   If so, the comma in his line serves the same purpose as the commas in my examples above.

Carrithers may view the participial phrase as an elision.   If he regards the complete thought as "He also saw a wandering ascetic who was bent on escaping these sufferings" then the comma marks where the words "who was" were dropped.

In any case, the comma in question is not strong enough to completely divorce the participial phrase from the closest noun.   In this sentence, it is the ascetic who is so bent.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, it's *ascetic*.

When speaking, clauses and phrases are denoted by natural small pauses in speech, and a comma can recreate that rhythm, making things easier to understand - particularly when reading.

Commas are only *needed* if an interrupting word or phrase would alter the meaning of things around it and you want to "isolate" it from clauses before or afterward.  Otherwise they are optional, but can really make things clearer and easier to read.

The sentence with *however* in it is a good example of where at least one of the commas is practically required.

> As he reached manhood, however, he was confronted by ...

Without the comma following *however* a reader might think it is modifying *was* and be caught off guard and potentially confused.

> He also saw a wandering ascetic, bent on escaping these sufferings
>
> He also saw a wandering ascetic bent on escaping these sufferings

Both of these mean the same.